# Call paint method in the game fps tick in java

Tags: java, loops, methods, paint, frame-rate

How do i call for my paint method to draw everything inside it withing my thick method that runs 60 times per second.

this is the fps calculation :

```
int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60;
    long maxWorkingTimePerFrame = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;  //this is optional
    long lastStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(true)
    {
        lastStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Tick();

        long processingTimeForCurrentFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastStartTime;
        if(processingTimeForCurrentFrame  < maxWorkingTimePerFrame)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(maxWorkingTimePerFrame - processingTimeForCurrentFrame);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("TSEngine :: run :: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

so how do i call :

```
public void paint( Graphics g ) {

}
```

in my Tick method?

Comment: Erm, call it from the implementation of your `Tick` method?

Comment: you mean like replace the paint method and use :
    public static void Tick(Graphics g){} instead?

Comment: I can't believe this question hasn't been asked already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call the `paint()` method in your Tick method, you need to call the `repaint()` method. In your loop, just add `repaint()` when you want your component to call the paint method that you  wrote.

Read this article, as it explains a little bit how painting and repainting work. http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/~mes/courses/cps530/programs/threads/Repaint/index.html.

Here is an article demonstrating how to call repaint. http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/~mes/courses/cps530/programs/threads/Repaint/RepaintApplet3.java

Comment: i tried this but all it gives me now is a empty white screen and i am unable to close the program

Comment: but it has to be infitie in order for it to be an fps loop right?

Comment: Create a thread that calls a method 60 times a second. In that method, put repaint().